# Past asylum seeker in the UK - can I now be a tier 2 dependent?

Tags: visas, uk

I went to the UK on a student visa and after it expired I did seek asylum,  but left the UK before I got a decision. My husband wants us to relocate to the UK, he is a nurse and he will be sponsered by a hospital and I will go as his dependent.

My question is will I face any problems in obtaining a tier 2 dependent visa since I was an asylum seeker? I left UK in July 2009 and I left without being asked to leave.

Answer (score 4):

Odds are high your application will be subjected to extra scrutiny. You've shown in the past that you are willing to exploit the rules in order to try and stay in the UK which will ring huge alarm bells.

However. If your situation is totally legitimate and your husband is granted this visa, your marriage to him is found to be genuine, etc... Then there's no official reason you should automatically be rejected.

Expect the burden of proof to be on you far stronger than is already the norm in the very strict British system.